# Differential Operators as vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Do differential operators form a vector space and if so can we safely say that the del operator is a vector?

Comment: The differential operator is a linear transformation on the space of functions.  But do differential operators form a vectors space?  Then that would suggest properties of vector addition, and scalar multiplication.  How do you propose to define those?

Comment: Covectors form a vector space, if the premise of your question is the misguided idea that there is an inherent distinction between vector spaces, that contain vectors, and "covector spaces" that contain "covectors" (and which are perhaps studied in "linear coalgebra").

Comment: The thing is that I was talking about del operator and pointing out that del operator by itself without and argument is not a vector, it is an operator. And he showed me that under coordinate transformation obviously the del transform as a covector indicating that it is a covector. However in some other sources people utterly refuse to call "del" as a vector. In a more abstract way if differential operators form a vector space I would be convinced that the del operator is vector, not like the ones living the Real space obv.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new answer, which hopefully goes more into the direction the OP was asking:

Asking whether something is a vector or not is **not** a meaningful question unless a vector space is specified. You can even go so far to say that everything is a vector and everything can be added, once you choose an appropriate vector space. For example both $\mathsf{Chicken}$ and $\mathsf{Cow}$ are elements of the [free vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) $V$ generated by the set $\{\mathsf{Chicken},\mathsf{Cow}\}$ and $3\cdot \mathsf{Chicken} + 23\cdot \mathsf{Cow} $ is a well defined element in $V$ and thus a vector.

Once you have chosen a vector space $V$, you just call every element in $V$ vector. Of course you can still ask, whether differential operators lie in a vector space for which addition and scalar multiplication are actually useful. And to this the answer is **yes**: Below I describe some constructions of sensible vector spaces which contain differential operators.

---

First you need to say what a differential operator is to you, for the sake of simplicity I will focus on linear DOs with smooth coefficients.

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open and $p\in\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ a polynomial, then $p(D)$ is the differential operator  given by replacing the monomials $x_i^k$ of $p$ by $\partial_i^k$. For example if $p(x_1,x_2)=-x_1^2-x_2^2$, then $p(D)$ is the Laplace-operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then
$$
V=\{p(D)\vert p \in\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\}
$$
is obviously a vector space (with the same addition and scalar multiplication as for polynomials), it even is a complex algebra. If you want differential operators with nonconstant coefficients you can take polynomials $p\in C^{\infty}(U)[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (here $C^\infty(U)$ is viewed as a ring).

In both cases there is an linear embedding $F\colon V\hookrightarrow \mathscr{L}(C_c^\infty(U),C_c^\infty(U))$ ($\mathscr{L}$ denotes the vector space of continuous and linear maps) where $F(p(D))u=p(D)u$ (the obvious application of the operator). The viewpoint that differential operators are a subspace of $\mathscr{L}(C_c^\infty,C_c^\infty)$ can be adapted in more general contexts: If $M$ is a smooth manifold then you can define the subspaces $\mathrm{Diff}^k(M)\subset \mathscr{L}(C_c^\infty(M),C_c^\infty(M))$ of linear DOs of order $k$ inductively by $\mathrm{Diff}^{-1}(M)=0$ and
$$
\mathrm{Diff}^{k+1}(M)=\{P\in \mathscr{L}(C_c^\infty(M),C_c^\infty(M))\vert \forall u\in  C^\infty(M): [P,u]\in \mathrm{Diff}^k(M)\},
$$
where $[P,Q]=PQ-QP$ is the commutator of operators and $u$ is viewed as operator that multiplies functions with $u$.

Comment: A more internal definition I've seen is something like: let $A$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.  Then a differential operator of order $\le n$ on $A$ is a function $A\to A$ such that for every $f_1, \ldots, f_{n+1} \in A$, we have: $$\sum_{S \subseteq [n+1]} (-1)^{|S|} \left(\prod_{i\notin S} f_i\right) D \left(\prod_{i\in S} f_i \right) = 0.$$  This then forms a filter of vector spaces, and also it turns out the composition of differential operators of order $\le m$ and $\le n$, respectively, is a differential operator of order $\le (m + n)$.  So, the union is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Comment: I am nowhere near to the mathematical maturity to understand your answer, however, thank you. All I was just trying to understand that is del operator a vector?, Of course in real space it is not, like you cannot add a regular vector to del and expect it to be closed under addition. But I was wondering can it be a vector in more general and abstract sense. That is why I asked do differential operators form a vector space if so I would totally accept that the del operator is a vector. I am sorry if I am not able articulate the issue very well.

Comment: See new answer.